# How can i initialize a linked list node with a single init call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to create a linked list in Python. My question is in the init function of the below code

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next_node = new_next


firstNode = Node(15)

secondNode = Node(20)

thirdNode = Node(25)

firstNode.next_node = secondNode
```

I want to ask if we can initialize a node (along with its data and the next node link) in a single init call?

In the above code, I am first passing the data attribute of the node in the init call, and then i am setting the link with the help of the next_node attribute. Is there a way to do both the things in a single init call?

Comment: Sure: `firstNode = Node(15, secondNode)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can achieve that by nesting your class instances.
For example, a one liner to set all three nodes in one call

```
thirdNode = Node(25, Node(20, Node(15)))
print(thirdNode.data)
print(thirdNode.next_node.data)
print(thirdNode.next_node.next_node.data)
```

Or breaking your code in calls such that the `next_node`is called into the constructor while instantiating the new `Node` object

```
firstNode = Node(15)
secondNode = Node(20, firstNode)
thirdNode = Node(25, secondNode)
print(thirdNode.data)
print(secondNode.data)
print(firstNode.data)
```

The output will be

```
25
20
15
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a functional version using `reduce`, build is reversed, being 4 the the root node data (you could reverse the data):

```
from functools import reduce
ll =  reduce(lambda x, y: Node(y, x), (1, 2, 3, 4), Node(0))
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/IncomparableCompatibleAddin)